# What is the best answer for finding the maximum sum possible in an array

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm

The question is :

Find the maximum sum possible in an array of positive integers by selecting the elements in such a way that no two elements are next to each other.

there is an answer like this :
but what is the best answer for this question

> Let's denote the array by "t" and index it from 0. Let f be a
>   function so that
>       f(k)=the maximal sum in the [0..k] subarray with the conditions of the problem. 
>       Now use dynamic programming:

```
f(0) = t[0]
f(1) = max{ t[0], t[1] }
f(k) = max{ f(k-2) + t[k], f(k-1) } if k >= 2

If the array has n elements we need f(n-1).
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution you proposed is [good one](http://www.glassdoor.com/Interview/Find-the-maximum-sum-possible-in-an-array-of-positive-integers-by-selecting-the-elements-in-such-a-way-that-no-two-elements-QTN_250824.htm).

Similar approach (page 7 [here](http://comscigate.com/Books/contests/icpc.pdf)):

Let `m[i]` be the maximum sum of any subarray that ends at the element `a[i]`.Then
`m[i]` is simply `max(a[i], m[i-1]+a[i])`.

This is `O(n).`

and you cant get anything below `O(n)` as you have to visit every item of the array atleast once to compute the result.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I think this is already the best answer.
Since you need O(n) to read in the data.
an O(n) algorithm is the fastest in the big-O notation.

Comment: The algorithm above is not O(n). My algorithms-analysis fu is not strong tonight, but the algorithm above is at least O(n lg n) or O(n^2).

Comment: I don't understand you. If you store f(i) in an array f[], then you just need to run calculate f[1]..f[n] each just once.

Comment: Ah, you're right. Nevermind me.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int maxSum(int[] A){
    return maxSum(A,0,1);
}
private static int maxSum(int[] A, int x, int y){
    int c =0, d=0;
    if(x<A.length){
        c = A[x]+maxSum(A,x+2,x+3);
    }
    if(y<A.length){
        d = A[y]+maxSum(A,y+2,y+3);
    }
    return c>d?c:d;
}
```